# Order list alphabetically but with certain elements always at the top

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
class Employee   
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<favorite> f = new List<favorite>();

        f.Add(new favorite {id = 1, title ="MEN" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 2, title = "WOMEN" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 3, title = "BOYS" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 4, title = "GIRLS" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 5, title = "Ajay" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 6, title = "vijay" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 7, title = "Jitu" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 8, title = "Suresh" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 9, title = "Ramesh" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 10, title = "Akshay" })

        foreach (var item in f.OrderBy(e=>e.title).ThenBy(e=>e.title))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.title);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class favorite
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The above list has 4 default favorites (`MEN`, `WOWEN`, `BOYS`, `GIRLS`), which I want to be always at the top and all other favorites in alphabetical order.

Example: I want output to be like

```
MEN
WOMEN
BOYS
GIRLS
AJAY
AKSHAY
JITU
LIKE
and so on ...
```

I want to execute this query using Entity Framework Lambda expressions.
I tried to do this with `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` but have not found a proper solution yet.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Show us the query you wrote that does not work

Comment: I think that above query is wrong .i am not doing anything with default favorites.any suggestions ??

Comment: @ajaysingh can you add additional field to your `favorite` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you don't want to change the `favorite` class, you can define a function like this somewhere,

```
private static int GetPrimaryOrder(string title)
    {
        switch (title)
        {
            case "MEN":
                return 1;
            case "WOMEN":
                return 2;
            case "BOYS":
                return 3;
            case "GIRLS":
                return 4;
            default:
                return 5;
        }
    }
```

and use it for initial ordering like,

```
foreach (var item in f.OrderBy(x => GetPrimaryOrder(x.title)).ThenBy(e => e.title))
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.title);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it flexible you should extend your class and add another property to indicate the sort/display order. Then can you sort or filter on this.

```
class favorite
{
    public favorite(){sortOrder = int.MaxValue;} // default constructor, set the sort order to highest value possible. Alternatively you can make this a nullable property with default null value.
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int sortOrder { get; set; } // default high, sorted on low to high
    public string title { get; set; }
}

// code in main method
f.Add( new favorite {id = 1, title ="MEN", sortOrder=1 });
f.Add(new favorite { id = 2, title = "WOMEN", sortOrder=2 });
f.Add(new favorite { id = 3, title = "BOYS", sortOrder=3 });
f.Add(new favorite { id = 4, title = "GIRLS", sortOrder=4 });
// rest of your code, note that boolean defaults to false if you do not set it so the rest of your instances do not require change

// Sort by the sort order first and then title. Sort order is small first to large last, if they are the same then they are sorted by title
foreach (var item in f.OrderBy(e=>e.sortOrder).ThenBy(e=>e.title))
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.title);
}
```

Alternatively you could hardcode the ids of the default classes and basically create 2 lists that you merge together after each is sorted but its not very flexible IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add new `Order` Property and then set your favorite

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add an extra field.

If you want to solve it using link only you can order by checking for uppercase. I figured the top ones are all uppercase so that is something you can order on.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<favorite> f = new List<favorite>();

        f.Add(new favorite { id = 1, title = "MEN" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 2, title = "WOMEN" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 3, title = "BOYS" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 4, title = "GIRLS" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 5, title = "Ajay" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 6, title = "vijay" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 7, title = "Jitu" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 8, title = "Suresh" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 9, title = "Ramesh" });
        f.Add(new favorite { id = 10, title = "Akshay" });

        var list = f.OrderByDescending(e => IsAllUpper(e.title)).ThenBy(e => e.title).ToList();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.title);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    class favorite
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    static bool IsAllUpper(string input)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(input[i]) && !Char.IsUpper(input[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: But all favorites are in uppercase.It was my mistake that I defined list in lowercase other than default favorites

Comment: In that case I would add an extra property to order on.